# The following key(s) are missing the <username> at the front when adding to GCP VM metadata

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine, metadata

I am trying to add a public `ssh` key in an GCP VM instance metadata.

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata <instance-name> --zone=us-east4-a  --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=id_rsa.pub
```

The key has the format

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2 ...
....root@hostname
```

Why am I getting this warning

```
WARNING: The following key(s) are missing the <username> at the front
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2 ...
....root@hostname
```

What is more, after adding the public key to the node's metadata and although I am inside the GKE cluster and I have connectivity to the private IP of the node the `ssh` process fails

```
ssh <private_ip_of_the_node>
root@<private_ip_of_the_node> Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Compute Engine VMs built from public images and most common operating systems don't allow root login with a password over SSH.  Here, you are using the GKE cluster Private IP [root@<private_ip_of_the_node>] which may not have the root permissions and this might give you Permission denied (publickey).

- Refer to this [Permission denied (publickey) troubleshooting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh-errors#permission_denied_publickey).
- By following this  [Enable root login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/root-ssh#enable_root_login) to the GKE Cluster.
- Add SSH keys by following this [official doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#metadata) .
- There could be several other reasons why, and the most common examples are explained in this [blog](https://linuxhint.com/ssh-permission-denied-publickey-error/) by John Otieno .